# SQL Server query to further summarize grouped data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume a table named *transactions* with two columns: *invoiceNumber* and *itemNumber*.  Multiple quantities of an item on a single invoice are reflected by multiple records in the table.  (I know this isn't an appropriate design, but I'm simplifying a more complex structure to get at the root question.)

I can determine the average number of unique items for each invoice with a query like:

```
SELECT invoiceNumber, COUNT(DISTINCT itemNumber) 
FROM transactions 
GROUP BY invoiceNumber
```

This query effectively ignores the quantity of an item, counting each one only once per invoice and shows the result for each invoice.

Instead of all this detailed information, however, all I really want is to determine the **average** number of unique items across **all** invoices.  That is, I just want to summarize the per-invoice information.  How do I do that?

Comment: Why you use `average number`? Maybe you want say `unique number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate the result you've already figured out how to obtain.

```
WITH DistinctCounts AS (
  SELECT invoiceNumber, COUNT(DISTINCT itemNumber) AS distinctItems
  FROM transactions 
  GROUP BY invoiceNumber
)
  SELECT AVG(distinctItems)
  FROM DistinctCounts
```

Comment: works well, though I had to add a semicolon at the beginning of the query to avoid a syntax error

Comment: Thanks. And to be precise, the semicolon you had to add was a terminator for the previous query, not part of this query. If you ran this query alone, it would be fine without a semicolon.  :)

Comment: I was running the query through an interface on a 3d party web app, and it wasn't apparent that I was running more than one query, so it was puzzling to figure that out!  ;-)  BTW, I found a very similar answer here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx under "B. Using a common table expression to limit counts and report averages"

Answer (score 0):

```
Select avg(numberininvoice)
From
(
Select invoicenumber, count(itemnumber) as numberininvoie
From
(Select distinct invoicenumber, itemnumber
From transactions) a
Group by invoicenumber
) b
```